# Jenkins not able to identify repo from bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

We are using two bitbucket repositories in a single pipeline job , the job is working fine in old jenkins but when we use the same configuration, same repo in new jenkins it is showing the error.
I am not able to find where this Use repository setting done

Error : No git repository configured in SCM configuration or plugin is configured wrong
Option 'Use repository' is set as: '.entitlement.git'
Please check the configuration

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check your Jenkins plugin list and their respective version, to make sure you have the same capabilities activated in the new Jenkins (same as the old Jenkins instance).

The [Git Parameter Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/#plugin-content-error-handling) does list a similar error message:

[image: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin@master/docs/images/image2019-2-17_17-2-14.png]

Check that `.entitlement.git` is the actual name of the repository (it could be `entitlement.git`, without the first '`.`'.